Can you find out if an Azure VM SKU has a temp disk, from the SKU?
I want to be able to find out if a particular SKU has a temp disk attached or not. I have tried using PowerShell and the Get-AzComputeResourceSku command, to list the capabilities, but there doesn't appear to be a property for it.
Same for the Resource SKU API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resource-skus/list?tabs=HTTP. (The PS command looks to use this API by the output)
I want to use the information in a Bicep deploy to decide on the layout of tempdb for a SQL Server on Azure VM deployment.
This seems such an obvious property to want to expose? Anyone achieved this?

I might have found the information. It looks to be exposed using a property called MaxResourceVolumeMB.
I'm checking a number of SKUs now to see if it aligns, but so far it looks good. Will attempt to find some docs on this too.

You can check the temp disk information for a VM SKU with MaxResourceVolumeMB. The MaxResourceVolumeMB value provides information about the local temp disk size.
Here is the PowerShell script to find the local temp disk information for all SKUs from specific locations.
$location = "EastUS" 
$vmskus = Get-AzComputeResourceSku | Where-Object { $_.Locations -contains $location -and $_.ResourceType -eq "virtualMachines" }

$vmSkuinfo = @()

foreach ($sku in $vmSkus) {

    $tempDiskCapability = $sku.Capabilities | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "MaxResourceVolumeMB" }

    if ($tempDiskCapability) {
    
        $maxResourceVolumeMB = [int]$tempDiskCapability.Value
        $maxResourceVolumeGB = [math]::Round($maxResourceVolumeMB / 1024, 2)
        
        $osDiskCapability = $sku.Capabilities | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "OSVhdSizeMB" }

        if ($osDiskCapability) {
        
            $osVhdSizeMB = [int]$osDiskCapability.Value
            $osVhdSizeGB = [math]::Round($osVhdSizeMB / 1024, 2)
        } else {
            $osVhdSizeMB = 0
            $osVhdSizeGB = 0
        }

        $vmSkuinfo += [pscustomobject]@{
            'VM SKU Name'          = $sku.Name
            'Location'             = $location
            'Local Temp Disk (MB)'  = $maxResourceVolumeMB
            'Local Temp Disk (GB)'  = $maxResourceVolumeGB
            'OS Disk Size (MB)'     = $osVhdSizeMB
            'OS Disk Size (GB)'     = $osVhdSizeGB
        }
    }
}

$CSVPath = "/home/venkatv/VM_SKU_DiskSizes.CSV"

$vmSkuinfo | Export-CSV -Path $CSVPath -AutoSize

Write-Output "Data exported to $CSVPath"


Output:

Here is the information on the local temp disk and OS disk for specific SKUs.

Reference: Azure VM sizes with no local temporary disk

Thanks, that confirms what I found yesterday.
Did you find this in some Microsoft documentation somewhere? I've not found anything documented confirming that this is the property.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Aside from images of text: Please avoid answering questions that are just requirements, such as the question here. Stack Overflow is not for authoring custom solutions when no programming question is presented, aside from a general need.
